Local superlinear convergence of Newton's method for $C^1$ functions
I am trying to prove that there exists an $\epsilon>0$, s.t. for $f\in C^1([a,b])$ with $$f(x_*)=0,\quad f'(x_*) \neq0$$ Newton's method converges superlinear for every starting point $$x_0\in[x_*-\epsilon,x_*+\epsilon].$$
So I already got the hint to show that $g(x):=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ is a contraction by using Taylor approx. with Peano remainder term. So I thought that maybe
\begin{align}
\big|g(x)-x_*\big|&=\big|x-x_*-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\big|\\
&=\big|x-x_*-\frac{(f(x_*)+f'(x_*)(x-x_*)+R_n)}{f'(x)}\big|\\
&=\big|x-x_*-\frac{(f(x_*)+f'(x_*)(x-x_*)+[f'(\xi)-f'(x_*)](x-x_*))}{f'(x)}\big|\\
&=\big|(x-x_*)[1-\frac{f'(\xi)}{f'(x)}]\big|
\end{align}
for $\xi\in(x_*,x)$.
Now I want to show that \begin{align}
\big|(x-x_*)[1-\frac{f'(\xi)}{f'(x)}]\big|&=|x-x_*||1-\frac{f'(\xi)}{f'(x)}|\leq\epsilon,
\end{align}
implying that $$g(U_\epsilon(x_*))\subset U_\epsilon(x_*),$$ making g a contraction and $x_*$ a fixed point of g.
But since $|x-x_*|<\epsilon$, this is equivalent to $$\frac{f'(\xi)}{f(x)} \leq 1\;\forall x\in[x_*-\epsilon,x_*+\epsilon],\;\xi\in(x_*,x).$$ Hence $|f'|$ would have to increase monotonically on $[x_*-\epsilon,x_*+\epsilon]$, which is not given in general.
Has anyone an idea to fix the proof or prove the statement in another way? Would be grateful for every kind of help :)

Can you use the (uniform) continuity of $f'$ to your advantage?

Are you sure about your equivalence? What happens when $f'(\xi)/f(x) = 1.2$? Can you bound $|f'(x) - f'(\xi)|$? near $x_*$?

I shall now provide an answer which is much closer to the approach pursued by the OP.
Let $z$ denote a zero of $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and assume that $f'(z) \not = 0$ so that the function $g$ given by
$$g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}.$$ is defined in a closed and bounded interval $U$ around $z$. Let $x \in U$ be given. Then by Taylor's formula there exists at least one $\xi$ between $x$ and $z$ such that
$$ f(x) = f(z) + f'(\xi)(x-z) = f'(\xi)(x-z).$$
It follows that
$$z - g(x) = z - x + \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = (z-x)\left(1 - \frac{f'(\xi)}{f'(x)} \right) = (z-x) \frac{f'(x) - f'(\xi)}{f'(x)} $$
I shall now estimate the terms involving the derivative of $f$. By assumption $f'$ is nonzero and continuous on the closed and bounded set $U$. It follows that exists $K > 0$ such that
$$ \frac{1}{|f(x)|} \leq K$$
for all $x \in U$. Moreover, since $f$ is $C^1$ we have that $f'$ is continuous. In particular, $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $U$. Given any $\epsilon > 0$ we can therefore find $\delta>0$ such that
$$\forall x,y \in U \: : \: |x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f'(x) - f'(y)| < \epsilon.$$
Our task is to establish the superlinear convergence of Newton's method. We have to show that the fraction
$$ \frac{z-x_{n+1}}{z-x_n} $$
is meaningful and tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Let therefore $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Since we are interested in small values of $\epsilon$, we may assume that $\epsilon < 1$. In any case, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$ \forall x,y \in U \: : \: |x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f'(x) - f'(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{K}.$$
Now assume that $x_n \in U$ satisfies
$$ |x_n - z| < \delta.$$
Then
$$ \left| \frac{z-g(x_n)}{z-x_n} \right| < \epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon < 1$ we conclude that $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ satisfies $$|x_{n+1}-z|< \delta.$$
In short, given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x_0-z|<\delta$, then Newton's method is defined for all $n$ and $|x_n - z| < \delta$ and
$$\left| \frac{z-x_{n+1}}{z-x_n} \right| < \epsilon.$$
This shows that Newton's method has local superlinear convergence when $f$ is $C^1$.

Let $z$ denote any zero of $f$, i.e., $f(z) = 0$ and let $g$ denote the function given by $$g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}.$$ Under very mild conditions it is possible find a function $C$ such that $$z - g(x) = C(x)(z-x).$$ The problem of analyzing the convergence of Newton's method to $z$ then reduces to finding the largest open interval $J$ around $z$ that contains no other zeros of $f$ and satisfies $$\forall x \in J \: : \: |C(x)| < 1.$$
We shall now derive a formula for $C$. We have
$$\begin{align}
z - g(x) 
&= z - x + \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \\
&= \frac{1}{f'(x)} \left( f'(x)(z-x) + f(x)\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{f'(x)} \left( f'(x)(z-x) - (f(z) - f(x)) \right)
\end{align}$$
We shall express $f(z) - f(x)$ in terms of $f'$. We consider the function $\phi : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$ \phi(s) = f(sz + (1-s)x).$$ It is clear that $\phi(1) = f(z)$ and that $\phi(0) = f(x)$. Moreover, $\phi$ is differentiable if $f$ is differentiable and $$\phi'(s) = f'(sz + (1-s)x)(x-z).$$ We conclude that
$$f(z) - f(x) = \phi(1) - \phi(0) = \int_0^1 \phi'(s) dx = \int_0^1 f'(sz + (1-s)x) (z-x) ds$$
Returning to the expression for $z -g(x)$ we observe that
$$z - g(x) = \left [ \frac{1}{f'(x)} \int_0^1 (f'(x) - f'(sz + (1-s)x)ds \right] (z-x),$$
which is why we define
$$ C(x) = \frac{1}{f'(x)} \int_0^1 (f'(x) - f'(sz + (1-s)x)ds $$
We observe that $C(z) = 0$ and $C$ is continuous, if $f'$ is continuous.

Thank you so much! Very interesting way of solving :)
